# How to use jQuery to assign / bind validation functions to input fields from a list dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML form with a number of input fields. I would like to validate some, but not all, of the input fields before submission. I do this using custom validation functions in jQuery. Each of these functions checks a field against some conditions. If the field fails, the function sets a custom HTML5 error message for that field using setCustomValidity() . For example:

```
$.fn.checkFoo = function() {
  let value = $("#foo").val();
  if (value == -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#foo")[0].setCustomValidity("Please choose one of the options.");
  }        
}
```

This is all fine and good. The custom message does not unset itself after the user chooses a valid option. The result of that is the submission is prevented. To correct for that I need another function to clear the custom message, like so:

```
$.fn.checkFooOff = function() {
  $("#foo")[0].setCustomValidity("");
}
```

Finally, I need a couple of functions to bind these two to an input field:

```
$("#foo").focusout(function(){
  $.fn.CheckFoo();
})

$("#foo").focus(function(){
  $.fn.CheckFooOff();
})
```

This method works. However, it takes 4 functions to handle the validation for 1 field. It all quickly piles up when I have more than 1 or 2 fields to validate.

The last 3 functions are largely identical, except for the function name and the field name. What I am thinking is some kind of meta function that accepts a list of function names and field names and generates the set of 4 functions for each field.

Or is there a better way?

P.S. Yes, I know I don't need to add the semicolons. However I am trying to preserve my coding style across several programming languages, so I don't make careless mistakes.

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: *I don't need to add the semicolons* - strange comment - has someone reviewed your code and said to *stop* using semicolons?  If anything you're missing them after the `variable = function() { .. };`

Comment: *using custom validation functions in jQuery* - so you're not using a validation library?  Write your validation as if it's a library - ie without any reference to "#foo" (using `this` instead, for example), then you should be able to have one `$.fn.addValidation = function...` and then `$("#foo").addValidation()` and the addValidation call add the various event handlers etc for you.

Comment: If you follow the jquery guidelines for creating "plugins" then you would also be able to do `$(list_of_inputs).addValidation()`

Comment: If your plugin/validation raises (.trigger) events, then individual controls can then listen for the event and provide custom validation.  eg `$("#foo").on("validate", function()..`

Comment: If you don't want to write your own (mini) validation plugin, then invest time in using an existing one, as linked above.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have looked at some jQuery validation plugins and none of them fulfill my requirements. Some validations I need to do is to compare an input with a list of values I pull in via Ajax to see if the input is on the list. Also, I would like to set my custom error messages so the user knows what's wrong.